# After timeshift ubuntu cant find which touch

Tags: timeshift

Long story short. I tried something yesterday in my ubuntu. It messed up my system a bit so i decide to timeshift to just one day before when everything was good.
After the timeshift the system was not booting and after i tried a bit it did. But trying to timeshift again gave me this message you can see in the picture.
I tried to reinstall coreutils but that does not work as well. less
0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtyOz.jpg)

Comment: _I tried something yesterday_ – I guess it would be helpful to elaborate on what exactly you tried …

Comment: I just removed everything related to neovim. But everything worked fin. Even after the timeshift. It was only after a restart that things started going south

Comment: … and how did you install and remove it? Did you use `apt`?

Comment: Yes. Just apt remove and the purge

Comment: You need to boot to a live CD/DVD/USB that you could install timeshift into, then restore from there.

Comment: @Terrance is there any online guide for this. Is it easy

Comment: The video at https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/ talks about restoring a system and what he used to do it with.  He uses [Linux Lite 5.0](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/release-announcements/linux-lite-5-0-final-released/) as he says it comes with Timeshift already installed.  You can build your own if you want.

Comment: @Terrance thank you mate. You are a life saver. I really didn’t know about this trick. Thanks again :)